# Nested Loop not iterating

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, loops, xna

In my code I have a nested loop which does not iterate with the exception of an if statement that always occurs no matter what the condition. Without the if statement the portion of the for loop's code which iterates the loop becomes unreachable. No matter what I have tried I have not been able to get the inside loop to iterate.

```
    class Map
    {
        public int Width { get; set; }
        public int Height { get; set; }
        public Vector2[] positions = new Vector2[500*500];

        private GroundVoxel[,] map = new GroundVoxel[500, 500];
        private Vector2 voxelPosition = new Vector2(0,0);
        private static int sizeX = 499, sizeY = 499, airLevel = 425;
        private int positionX = 0, positionY = 0, vectorNumber = 0;

        public Map()
        {
        }
        public Vector2[] Initialize()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= sizeY; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= sizeX; j++) <-- This does not iterate.
                {
                    map[positionX, positionY] = new GroundVoxel(voxelPosition);
                    voxelPosition.X += 80;
                    positions[vectorNumber] = voxelPosition;
                    vectorNumber += 1;
                    if (j == sizeX) <-- This always executes even though j != sizeX.
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                voxelPosition.Y += 80;
                voxelPosition.X = 0;
            }
            return positions;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Step through the code. Verify that `sizeX` is >0. If your loop never iterates, then the condition to exit the loop is met before it even starts iterating.

Comment: Put a break point on the `break;` and make sure the values of j and sizeX are what you expect (both 499).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the fully qualified name to refer to a static class member variable like your `sizeX` and `sizeY`.
  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is an article on the subject.

Hope this helps!

Comment: "To refer to the static member x, use the fully qualified name (*unless it is accessible from the same scope*)" sizeX and sizeY are being accessed from within the same class so they are within scope. Fully qualifing the name will not hurt, but is not needed.

Comment: Unless there is a locally defined sizeX and sizeY that is.

Answer (score 0):

I think we'll need more code. I've copied your code into a basic winforms test application and both of my loops iterates as expected.

I'm not familiar with XNA or what a "VoxelPosition" is, but I think you have a lurking bug here:

```
voxelPosition.X += 80;
positions[vectorNumber] = voxelPosition;
```

You are simply storing the same pointer in a very large array -- all of the entries will be pointing to the same object.

You will need to declare another object every time through the loop to store individal vector entries.

Hope this helps?

Comment: voxelPosition is a Vector2 which is a struct. A new copy is put in the array (not a pointer).

Comment: Ahhh. It looks like a class from this code snippet. Domain knowledge helps here, hey? :)

Comment: Yeah, I've worked with XNA a bit in the past. You of course would be right if it were actually a class.